# AWS RDS ReplicaLag metric missing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

We have two mariadb instances running that we are trying to monitor replication status of.

When I look in cloudwatch I am not seeing the metric for ReplicaLag anywhere. Is it not available for certain configurations or something? These two instances are replicas of non-aws hosted DBs so I am guessing that may be a factor.

Any thoughts of some way to monitor this? I had looked at adding to our zabbix but it seems like that also just uses the replicalag metric.

ReplicaLag metric to be available.

Comment: Have you figured out the issue? I have the same problem, ReplicaLag metric disappeared for me around the same time you made this post.